# Xbox One vs. Xbox 360 Achievements

Tags: xbox-360, achievements, xbox-one

So I recently bought an Xbox One after owning a Xbox 360 for quite a while. I recently also took up achievement hunting before my Xbox One. I liked the nice little square of an achievement on the 360. But after getting the one I realized the achievements are actually home page wallpapers and usually lame images. Is there a way to have like the 360? Like far cry 4 achievements for the 360 are totally customized for every one, but for the Xbox One they are all the same lame wallpaper! Like really? So my main question here is, is there a way to have normal xbox 360 achievements like before or am I stuck with these crappy wallpapers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is kind of dependant on what the game does. some games have specific wallpapers for achievements while others use a simple image.

The custom backgrounds was part of the [November 2014](http://news.xbox.com/2014/11/xbox-one-november-system-update-available) update which was around the same time Far Cry 4 [launched](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1AVSA_enUS504US504&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=far%20cry%204%20release%20date&es_th=1), so it's understandable they did not have specific backgrounds. It's also a third party game, so I'm not sure that they wanted to put in the extra work in creating images for each achievement.

You can set a custom background to whatever you want, it doesn't have to be an achievement. You can read up on a guide and get a template for custom backgrounds [here](http://majornelson.com/2014/10/22/heres-make-xbox-one-background/).

but... to answer your question: **no**, there is no way to use 360 style achievements on the XB1

Comment: good answer, just to add on: i get achievement art or any game art from the web, put it on a hard drive, plug that hard drive into the xbox, and set pic as background from media player